# Bluetooth connection using bluetooth MAC and PIN from code only

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am doing an APP to configure/control battery powered devices using Bluetooth.
The devices are not "visible" to save energy.

I have a ready list of about 50 device. The list contains the Bluetooth MAC address and the required PIN to pair.

When the APP starts up, I prompt the user to select a device from the list.
So now I want to automatically bind with the device, if not already done yet, without the need for the user to enter the PIN again.

I googled a lot, but did not exactly find what I was looking for (at least what I understood).
But I have to admit that I am pretty new to android programming and might simple not get the hint-
I also assume I do not use the right terms to search.
I found some "hacks" that simply suppress the PIN entry.

Can someone help me out here?

I already had the APP up and running if I manually bind the device, so the SPP communication is not the problem, it's mainly how to provide the PIN for connection.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello. Have you resolved your query? I stuck with similar problem.

Comment: Sorry no.
I currently decided to skip this part and look into this later on, when i find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new bond with bluetooth device by calling BluetoothDevice `setPin(byte[] pin)` and `createBond()` methods. You need also set BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission.

[public boolean createBond ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond%28%29)

[public boolean setPin (byte[] pin)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#setPin%28byte[]%29)

Comment: I found the setPin() and createBond().
I am still a bit lost.
I do the createBond() and then have to do a BroadcastReceiver to get the Intent for ??? and then call setPin()
At least, this is what I understand.
But I did not find a good answer what Intent I have to wait for. I thought "ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED" would be right, but not sure.
Isn't there a good step by step description ?